# Return value depending the boolean value of some var

Tags: php, variable-assignment, boolean-expression

I have a `Callback` function, that, the second parameter is an `Array`.
So, I have something like:

```
public function foo ($something, $callback) {
  /**
   * function body
   */
  $booleanOrArray = $this->bar();

  if ( is_callable ( $callback ) ) {
    return call_user_func ( $callback, !is_array($booleanOrArray), $booleanOrArray || [ ]);
  }
  throw new Exception('A callback function must be defined.');
}
```

So, in the `call_user_func`, there's a var that is called `$booleanOrArray`. This is because, if the procces of the function `bar` is well done, then, returns an `Array` with data, otherwise, the bar function returns `false`; so, if `bar` returns `false`, the first parameter in the `callback` function is determined by `is_array($booleanOrArray)`, so, if foo returns `false`, there is an error, and, if is an `Array`, this param will be `false`.

But, in my app, I force to the user to define the `callback` function as follows:

```
$MyClass = new ClassInstance();
$MyClass->foo('firstParam', function ( $error, Array $data ) {
  if ( ! $error ) {
    var_dump($data);
  }
  else {
    print 'Hey!';
  }
});
```

But, after all these code, I was surprised to realize that `$booleanOrArray || [ ]` always returns `false`.

In Javascript, if I code `var x = foo || bar;`, if `foo` is `null`, or `false`, or `undefined`, then `x` will have the `bar` value, and vice versa.

So, the question:

- Is this possible in php, or I have to do something like `$x = ($booleanOrArray) ? $booleanOrArray : [ ]` ?
- Do you have any idea to improve the callback function in this case? *(not opinion based, only standards)*

Comment: Suggestion: You can use the `callable` type hint instead of manually enforcing it and throwing an exception.

Comment: In my real app, I'm getting the function params dinamycally by func_get_args(), but it's a great data, thanks!

Comment: You can use something like this: `$x = true or $x = []; var_dump($x);` and `$x = false or $x = []; var_dump($x);` but short ternary operator suggested by @dev-null-dweller seems even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> something like `$x = ($booleanOrArray) ? $booleanOrArray : [ ]` ?.

Yes, you can even use shortened ternary syntax:

```
$booleanOrArray ?: []
```

This results  in `$booleanOrArray` if it is not falsy or empty array otherwise.